# extract filename between last slash and question mark

Tags: php, regex

I want to extract filename between last slash and question mark using **regex**
I read some related answers

```
([^/]*$)
```

But i have several domain names so i want to extract filename of specific names and looking for a regex that work for all domains.
How can i limit it to certain domains?
My target is to replace the domain name,

```
http://old.domain.com/asda/dsdasd/fsdfd/bvc/filename.mp4?fdgfsdgfgfsgf
http://new.domain.com/filename.mp4
```

Sincerely

Comment: Could you clearly specify what you want to match in your examples?

Comment: I wrote a example in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
preg_replace('/(.*:\/\/).*\/(.*?)(\?.*|$)/', '$1new.domain.com/$2', $url );
```

replacing the full domain and path with the new one.

[See it here at Ideone](http://ideone.com/sgl656).

**Edit:**

Or if you really need to extract the filename (as you say in the question) try

```
preg_match('/[^\/]+?(?=\?|$)/', $url, $matches);
```

[as showed here.](http://ideone.com/dCip44)

Answer (score 1):

For your this specific problem use this solution or please elaborate your question with example

```
<?php
$url = 'http://old.domain.com/asda/dsdasd/fsdfd/bvc/filename.mp4?fdgfsdgfgfsgf';
//var_dump(parse_url($url));

$scheme= parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME);   // http
$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);   //old.domain.com
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);  //asda/dsdasd/fsdfd/bvc
$filename = basename($path); //filename.mp4
echo $newUrl = $scheme.'//new.domain.com/'.$filename;
?>
```

output

```
http//new.domain.com/filename.mp4
```

for more info about `parse_url` Please read http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: I want to use regex